# Connect SVG circles using Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, svg, visualization

I am trying to connect SVG circles and rectangles  by drawing lines between source circles and target rectangles. Here is the format of my json file:

```
    [{"sourceNode":"1","type":"sourceNode"},
     {"sourceNode":"3","type":"sourceNode"},
     {"sourceNode":"8","type":"sourceNode"},
     .....
     {"targetNode":"1","type":"targetNode"},
     {"targetNode":"7","type":"targetNode"},
     {"targetNode":"1","type":"targetNode"},
     .....
     {"type":"link","source":"1","target":"2"},
     {"type":"link","source":"3","target":"4"},
     {"type":"link","source":"3","target":"5"}]
```

I am using a tick function to give attributes to circles and the line. The circles work just fine, but I don't get lines with no attributes when I inspect my SVG in html.

Here is the code :

```
var nodeSource = g.selectAll("circle")
    .data(data.filter(function (d){ return d.type == "sourceNode"; }))
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("r", 5)
    .style("fill", "blue")
        .call(force.drag);

 var nodeTarget = g.selectAll("rect")
    .data(data.filter(function (d){ return d.type == "targetNode"; }))
    .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("width", 10)
    .attr("height", 10)
    .style("fill", "green")
        .call(force.drag);

    var link = g.selectAll("line")
    .data(data.filter(function (d){ return d.type == "link"; }))
    .enter().append("line")
        .style("stroke-width", "2")
        .style("stroke", "grey")
        .call(force.drag);

function tick(e) {
    nodeSource
      .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x = Math.max(radius(), Math.min(width() - radius(), d.x)); })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y = Math.max(radius(), Math.min(height() - radius(), d.y)); });

    nodeTarget
      .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x = Math.max(radius(), Math.min(width() - radius(), d.x)); })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y = Math.max(radius(), Math.min(height() - radius(), d.y)); });

    link
      .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
      .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })   
      .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
      .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

         chart.draw()

}
```

Comment: Are you using force layout? What did you give to force.nodes()? It seemed like a reference missing in force.nodes and force.links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're assigning `x1`, `x2`, etc. coordinates to your line, you're not actually giving them a value. In your json file, the data for links has:

```
"source": "1"
```

for example. Using `d.source.anything` won't return a value because `"1"` doesn't have any properties attached to it. If you want to get a reference to the node which has this number, you have to use `d3` to find it:

```
line.attr('x1', function (d) {
        return d3.selectAll('circle').filter(function (k) {
            return d.source === k.sourceNode;
        }).attr('cx');
    })
```

Then, when you want to do the target nodes:

```
line.attr('x2', function(d) {
        return d3.selectAll('rect').filter(function (k) {
            return d.target === k.targetNode;
        }).attr('x');
    })
```